# nginx reverse proxy pop3 send hostname to auth script

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, pop3

I have set up a POP3 reverse proxy and is being used to serve multiple domains. I was thinking to pass the hostname of the request to the auth script as a custom header, but I don't know how.

The relevant section of the nginx.conf file is:

```
mail {
    server_name mail.example.com;
    auth_http  10.169.15.199:80/auth_script.php;
    auth_http_timeout 5000;
    proxy  on;
    proxy_pass_error_message on;

    pop3_capabilities "LAST" "TOP" "USER" "PIPELINING" "UIDL";

    server {
      protocol    pop3;
      listen      110;
      pop3_auth   plain;
      auth_http_header X-Auth-Port 110;
      auth_http_header User-Agent "Nginx POP3/IMAP4 proxy";
      auth_http_header my_hostname $host;
    }
}
```

I tried with this:

```
auth_http_header my_hostname $host;
```

expecting nginx to replace the $host with the actual hostname, but it does not happen, the auth script receives $_SERVER[MY_HOSTNAME] = '$host'.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to get the host of the auth, is authenticating like `user@hostname.tld` and in the auth headers split the part of the hostname.

If you want to proxy auth to multiple domains I wrote a [module in perl](https://github.com/falcacibar/nginx_auth_imap_perl)